# Template or Component on angular 4?

Tags: angular

I am on learning phase of angular4. Now creating single app. but want to know which is better, templating or better to work via component for each modules?

Comment: You may want to read this. https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

Comment: Yes, i have read this. What will you prefer?

Comment: Use external *.html template files. Don´t put HTML code into the component. If thats the question. You may want to have a look at Angular CLI since this applies the styleguide in most cases.

Comment: what do you mean by `templating`?

Comment: I have tried with making separate for each page or modules like this. http://prntscr.com/geak62
But developer used template for dom element instead of templateUrl
So asking which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why?** One component per file makes it far easier to read, maintain, and avoid collisions with teams in source control.

**Why?** One component per file avoids hidden bugs that often arise when combining components in a file where they may share variables, create unwanted closures, or unwanted coupling with dependencies.

**Why?** A single component can be the default export for its file which facilitates lazy loading with the router.
for more details https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

So the **Conclusion** is if you have modular structure it will help you to easily understand and easy maintainable as your application grows big. So it is recommended to follow these coding practices to avoid any issues while your are in mid developing phase.

Comment: Thanks mate... Module structure means like this way, right?
http://prntscr.com/geak62

Comment: Yes, but if you still have some questions about structure then you can refer some of the ongoing open source projects of angular 2 like https://github.com/aviabird/angularspree

Comment: I have tried from this repo. https://github.com/preboot/angular-webpack
How can i use angular cli on existing project?

Comment: Install Angular 2 cli globally and generate new project through angular cli command then it will automatically setup webpack with angular 2. Follow steps in Angular quick start https://angular.io/guide/quickstart . Here is angular cli documentation https://cli.angular.io/